# PowerShell tee-object within a .ps1 script?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a script that is executed as follows:
.\script.ps1 “param1” “param2” 2>&1 | tee -filePath buildlog.txt

I can't find a way to do the following..  logging to both the console and file encapsulated within the script.
.\script.ps1 “param1” “param2”

Here's my attempt at doing it:

## powershelltest.ps1

```
param([string]$paramOne, [string]$paramTwo)

function DoWork()
{
 Write-Host '3'
}

function WriteLogFile()
{
    DoWork
 # The following would not be captured by Start-Transcript & Stop-Transcript
 # program.exe ....
 Write-Host '4'
}

function CollectorFunction()
{
    Write-Host '2'
 WriteLogFile;
    Write-Host '5'
}

Write-Host '1'
CollectorFunction 2>&1 | tee -filePath c:\log.foo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write to a log file don't use `Write-Host`.  Use `Write-Output` or don't use `Write-*` at all because `Write-Output` is the default e.g:

```
Write-Output 'hello' > foo.txt
```

is equivalent to:

```
'hello' > foo.txt
```

`Write-Output` sends output to the stdout stream (ie 1).  Use `Write-Error` to send output to the error stream (ie 2).  These two streams can be redirected.  `Write-Host` more or less writes directly to the host UI bypassing output streams altogether.

In PowerShell V3, you can also redirect the following streams:

```
The Windows PowerShell redirection operators use the following characters
to represent each output type:
  *   All output
  1   Success output
  2   Errors
  3   Warning messages
  4   Verbose output
  5   Debug messages
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Start-Transcript`.  The only caveat is that it doesn't capture standard output, only output from `Write-Host`.  So, you just have to pipe the output from legacy command line applications to `Write-Host`:

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\logs\mylog.log
program.exe | Write-Host
```

Comment: Start-Transcript does not catch stdout of non-builtin commands, as you say; but I see that it *does* capture stdout of Powershell commands (e.g. `Write-Out` is captured), as of version 4.0